# how to install java 1.5 jdk in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu

make

You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: java version "1.6.0_35".
The correct version is: 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

For the users who are trying it on Ubuntu following are the steps I followed. This is done in Ubuntu 16.04. Hopefully it should work for Ubuntu 10.04+

These are the steps for ubuntu 16.04.

Download JDK 5 (jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64-rpm.bin) from the [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html).

Run the following commands in the given order.

```
 sudo su 
 chmod a+x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64-rpm.bin 
 ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64-rpm.bin 
 apt install alien 
 alien jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.rpm 
 dpkg -i jdk_1.5.022-1_amd64.deb
```

If you use rpm to install the .rpm, you will get following error.

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
glibc >= 2.1.2-11 is needed by jdk-2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.i586
sh-utils >= 2.0-1 is needed by jdk-2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.i586
fileutils >= 4.0-8 is needed by jdk-2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.i586
gawk >= 3.0.4-1 is needed by jdk-2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.i586
textutils >= 2.0-2 is needed by jdk-2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.i586
```

So I used alien and dpkg to handle it with usual package installing in java. Hope this will help to somebody who is trying to work with java 1.5 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think you can just download the non-rpm version and install by: chmod a+x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin and
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.5 is too old. Just look at reasons for using  1.5, and figure out if you can work with Java 8, which is the latest one.

But in-case of no workarounds,

Download the archive from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html

Create directory for JDK:

`sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/java5`

Extract archive in a new folder:

`sudo tar xf java5.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/java5`

Now run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/javaws" 1
```

Correct the file ownership and the permissions of the executables:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0
```

Check if it successful:

`java -version`

Comment: no such option: java5.tar.gz  on a given link